# What exception should I throw during data validation

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, validation

I have a commercial program with an abstract employee class. This class has an abstract property called `BaseSalary` to be implemented in its derived classes according the employee type (cashier, supervisor, manager and so on).

I want to validate data in the `BaseSalary` properties for a given range of salary depending on the position.

What kind of exception should I throw when the salary doesn't match the requirements for that position job?

Comment: Create your own `OutOfSalaryRange` exception?

Comment: Is your program intended to be distributed to other development teams, potentially at other companies, or will only your your team be catching the error?

Comment: it's just testing stuff, if I'm going to mess up is better now as a student, jajajja

Comment: I'd look at ways to validate data passed to the Property to **avoid** an exception.  Maybe each concrete Type could have a MinSalary and MaxSalary property used to validate data before it is passed.

Comment: @marc_s like create my own exception class inheriting from exception?

Comment: Once you generate this exception, what are you going to do with it?  I'm in the school of thought that says exceptions should only be for exceptional events, and a screwed up salary is not that exceptional.

Comment: the point is to throw the excpetion to avoid possible logic errors

Comment: @blade  A logic error is something that you have control over.  Your testing should be eliminating them.  An exception is something like a hardware failure for which you cannot ever control.

Comment: so how I let somebody know that the entered salary is not correct. i don't wanna fix the salary by myself, i want that person realize and rectify it

Comment: @Blade that leads to user entry data validation for which there are many solutions depending on the structure of your program (e.g. see Plutonix's answer).  In general you should not allow users to enter information that conflicts with business logic requirements. In practice that can take a lot of work. For example, is the salary wrong, or is the salary **range** wrong. BTW prepending a users name with `@` means that the stack overflow system will inform them that you directed a comment at them

Comment: @Peter M: This is very good advice - business logic should not be handled by exceptions .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than throw exceptions, then write more code elsewhere to catch and handle them, explore not allowing out of range values at all:

```
Public Class Waitress
    Inherits Employee

    Public Sub New
       MyBase.GetsTips = True
       ' do other stuff including class specific params from wherever
       MyBase.MinSalary = minsalary from whereever you store it

       ' or maybe.....
       MyBase.MaxSalary = SalaryClass.GetMax(enumEmp.Waitress)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Elsewhere

```
If newSalary >= myWaitress.MinSalary AndAlso
      newSalary <= myWaitress.MaxSalary Then

     myWaitress.Salary = newSalary
End IF
```

In the real world, the range is often more complex than simply by department.  In addition to department, there might be training requirements, salary tiers, tenure requirements and so forth.  In that case, you might have a Salary class to help determine the correct range for **this** waitress (based on training etc etc etc), not simply *any* waitress:

```
If newSalary >= SalaryClass.GetMin(myWaitress) AndAlso
          newSalary <= SalaryClass.GetMax(myWaitress) Then

     myWaitress.Salary = newSalary
Else
     ' tell user that is an invalid amount
End IF
```

Comment: something *like* a `SalaryClass` could be used much further upstream such as validating the contents of a TextBox/NumericUpDn so the issue can be described to the user when they Click OK and all the data on the form is checked over.

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to stick with the exceptions provided by the framework. To your case, i would use an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` to describe that the value was out of range.

Of course, you could always create a custom `XXXException` in case you want to describe something more specific to your domain.

Comment: You can do the best of both worlds, make your own `XXXException` derived from `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`